# How to calculate different time from array value

Tags: php, arrays

My array as bellow :

```
$data = [
'0' => [
    'depart' => '2021-02-09 10:50:00',
    'arrival' => '2021-02-09 13:10:00',
],
'1' => [
    'depart' => '2021-02-09 14:50:00',
    'arrival' => '2021-02-09 15:30:00',
],
'2' => [
    'depart' => '2021-02-09 18:20:00',
    'arrival' => '2021-02-09 19:40:00',
]
```

];

From above array, I want to calculate different time to be :

```
0 = calculate different time between [0]['arrival'] and [1]['depart']
1 = calculate different time between [1]['arrival'] and [2]['depart']
```

My code :

```
$diff_time = [];
foreach ($data as $d => $dta) {
    $diff_time[$d] = timeDifference($dta['arrival'], $dta['depart']);
}
```

Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: I think that is for between single start and end date only. How about with value as array above. Could you please advise when this question has been submitted. I can not find. Thank you

Comment: It's easy enough to adapt the code in the duplicate to process your array, for example as is shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something below, then you can use any variable from `date_diff` like [y] => 0

> [m] => 0
> [d] => 0
> [h] => 2
> [i] => 50
> [s] => 0

```
$data = [
'0' => [
    'depart' => '2021-02-09 10:50:00',
    'arrival' => '2021-02-09 13:10:00',
],
'1' => [
    'depart' => '2021-02-09 14:50:00',
    'arrival' => '2021-02-09 15:30:00',
],
'2' => [
    'depart' => '2021-02-09 18:20:00',
    'arrival' => '2021-02-09 19:40:00',
] ];


$diff_time = [];
foreach ($data as $d => $dta) {
    if(isset( $data[$d+1]) &&  $data[$d+1]){
        $dif = date_diff( date_create($data[$d]['arrival']), date_create($data[$d+1]['depart']));
        $diff_time[$d] = $dif;
    }
    
}
print_r($diff_time);
```

You will get output printed like:

Array

```
(
    [0] => DateInterval Object
        (
            [y] => 0
            [m] => 0
            [d] => 0
            [h] => 1
            [i] => 40
            [s] => 0
            [weekday] => 0
            [weekday_behavior] => 0
            [first_last_day_of] => 0
            [invert] => 0
            [days] => 0
            [special_type] => 0
            [special_amount] => 0
            [have_weekday_relative] => 0
            [have_special_relative] => 0
        )

    [1] => DateInterval Object
        (
            [y] => 0
            [m] => 0
            [d] => 0
            [h] => 2
            [i] => 50
            [s] => 0
            [weekday] => 0
            [weekday_behavior] => 0
            [first_last_day_of] => 0
            [invert] => 0
            [days] => 0
            [special_type] => 0
            [special_amount] => 0
            [have_weekday_relative] => 0
            [have_special_relative] => 0
        )

)
```